# Loaded data from fetch instead of static data is not working properly react native

Tags: react-native, fetch-api, use-state, setstate

I have a bit of code that is trying to fetch some data and save it to update a list array but is is not updating it. The code below is some hard coded array that works fine but in the second I try to fetch the data but nothing?

Any idea where I am going wrong, I am not really getting the hang of this. Thanks

The code which works :-

```js
const data = [
  {id: '1', name: 'A'},
  {id: '2', name: 'B'},
  {id: '3', name: 'C'},
  {id: '4', name: 'D'},
  {id: '5', name: 'E'}
];

export default function App() {
const [lists, setLists] = useState(data);
```

And what I am trying to use to fetch :

```js
export default function App() {
  const fetchURL = 'https://www.uberfantasies.com/rn.php'
    
  const [lists, setLists] = useState('');

  const getData = () =>
    fetch(fetchURL)
      .then((res) => res.json());

  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then((lists) => setLists(res.data)  // If I use data it can display the hard coded array //
  }, []);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try logging lists and make sure it has data even after the API call.

Comment: The API you're using doesn't return valid JSON so `res.json()` will fail. If it's your API, you should fix it first

Comment: You also have some syntax errors and general typos. Once you get the API responding correctly, you should use `getData.then(setLists)` (or more verbosely `getData().then(data => setLists(data))`)

Answer (score -1):

This will load the data once and update the list when the component mounts

```
const [lists, setLists] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchURL = 'https://www.uberfantasies.com/rn.php'
  fetch(fetchURL)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => setLists(json?.data))
    .catch(console.warn)
}, [])
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything different to OP's code other than fix a typo

Comment: @Phil ah I see when I formatted the code it looked different, guess it may just be the typo

Comment: im wondering too haha

Answer (score -1):

Can you log the response of your getData function instead of setting it to state? Also can you refactor your function to something like this pls.

Also, in the useEffect function, where did that `res` variable come from? I assume it should be `lists`.

```
const getData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(fetchURL);
  console.log(res);
  const json = await res.json();
  console.log(json);
  return json;
};

useEffect(() => {
  getData().then((lists) => console.log(lists));
}, [])
```